# make rake db:create setup another database besides development, test or production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-audited

I'm using rails 4.2 and trying to configure (in a already established application) the Audited Gem following [this second database approach](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited/issues/257).

My config/database.yml file was as follows:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  host:  <%= ENV["MYSQL_HOST"] %>
  username: <%= ENV["MYSQL_USER"] %>
  password: <%= ENV["MYSQL_PASSWORD"] %>
  database: <%= ENV["MYSQL_DATABASE"] %>

test:
  <<: *default
  host:  <%= ENV["MYSQL_HOST"] %>
  username: <%= ENV["MYSQL_USER"] %>
  password: <%= ENV["MYSQL_PASSWORD"] %>
  database: <%= ENV['TEST_ENV_DB'] %>
```

And I intend to make it work for another db, besides development, test or production. However the task `rake db:create` only creates my development and test database. Is this possible to accomplish in my rails version?

```
audition:
  <<: *default
  host:  <%= ENV["MYSQL_HOST"] %>
  username: <%= ENV["MYSQL_USER"] %>
  password: <%= ENV["MYSQL_PASSWORD"] %>
  database: <%= ENV["AUDITION_DATABASE"] %>
```

Note the new name for audition database

Answer (score 1):

if you want to read/write to a seconds database in rails < 6

create a module

```
module AuditionConn
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
     if Rails.env == 'development'
       establish_connection "audition-development" # database.yml
      else
       establish_connection "audition-production" # database.yml
      end
    end
  end
end
```

then include it in any model you want to read/write from/to auditions database

```
class AuditionDBModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include AuditionConn
end
```

migration for second database

```
def up
  AuditionDBModel.connection.create_table ... do |t|
    ...

  AuditionDBModel.connection.change_column ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for the migration. Do you have any idea in how to make the rake db:create/drop automate this step for the second db together?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to create a new environment call `audition`, Right?!.

- Clone an existing environment file for instance, `config/environments/test.rb` and rename it `config/environments/audition.rb`
- Add a new configuration block in config/database.yml for your environment.
- Update any other configuration file you might have under the config folder with your new environment, some gems need to config it.
- Now you can start the server

`rails server -e audition`

Comment: No, I need to setup the audition database, to be used like the approach in the pointed link. Something to make it possible to be created with rake db:create alongside others databases. The same for rake db:migrate

Comment: @intmarinoreturn0 try to use octopus gem https://github.com/thiagopradi/octopus

Comment: you can be using `replication` on octopus gem, all write queries will be sent to master and read queries to slaves

Comment: Does that mean It wont be possible to write on my second db? In this case the audition one. This is not the purpose of the audited gem

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you:
  create another model for audit:

```
class AuditModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  connects_to database: { writing: :audit_db, reading: :audit_db}
end
```

or

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter:  "mysql2",
  host:     "localhost",
  username: "myuser",
  password: "mypass",
  database: "somedatabase"
)
```

for details:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html
https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionHandling.html